# Is a uniformly continuous function always continuous? Does continuity imply uniform continuity?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, uniform-continuity

Is a uniformly continuous function always continuous? Does continuity imply uniform continuity?

I'm struggling a bit in deciphering the difference between these. Can you strategically prove the assertions?

Comment: Everyone struggles with this; this means that the question has been asked and answered here many times before. Try [How exactly can't δ depend on x in the definition of uniform continuity?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305793/how-exactly-cant-delta-depend-on-x-in-the-definition-of-uniform-continuity) or the questions in the "Linked" column of that one, or try [a search for "continuous uniformly-continuous difference"](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22uniformly+continuous%22+difference).

Comment: The short answers are: uniformly continuous functions are always continuous, but not vice versa in general.

Comment: Thanks MJD! Read through that link and understood the concept much better :)

Answer (score 1):

Any function f that is uniformly continuous is also continuous. However, not all continuous functions are uniformly continuous. However, if we have a compact metric space and our function f is continuous, then f is also uniformly continuous.