# Why is $f(x) = x^2$ uniformly continuous on [0,1] but not $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, epsilon-delta, uniform-continuity

According to [How exactly can't $\delta$ depend on $x$ in the definition of uniform continuity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305793/how-exactly-cant-delta-depend-on-x-in-the-definition-of-uniform-continuity)

There is a lot of agreement that $x^2$ is not uniformly continuous. But is $x^2$ uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$?

For example:

> Let $f(x) = x^2$, then $|f(x) - f(x_0)| < |(x-x_0)(x+x_0)| < 2|x-x_0|$
>
> Let $|x - x_0| < \delta$, then $|f(x) - f(x_0)| < 2\delta$
>
> Therefore if $\delta = \epsilon/2$ then $|f(x) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon$
>   is satisfied and since $\delta$ does not depend on $x$ therefore $f(x) = x^2$ is uniformly continuous

Wouldn't the same proof be applied for $\mathbb{R}$ as well as all subsets of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Your proof is fine. Every continuous function on a compact set is uniformly continuous.

Comment: @ihf Sorry I am confused as to why are other posters claiming that the function is not uniformly continuous?

Comment: Other posters are claiming it is not uniformly continuous on other domains, such at $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Shouldn't the first `<` sign on the first line be `=`? Because $|f(x)−f(x_0)|$ is actually equal to $|(x−x_0)(x+x_0)|$ if $f(x)=x^2$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The comments and other answer address the uniform continuity on compact sets. @hermes points out the crux of your proof, that $|x + x_0| < 2$, cannot be extended to all of $\mathbb{R}$. Turns out there is no fix for that.

Let $\varepsilon = 1$. We need to show that for all $\delta > 0$, there exist $x,y$ such that $|x - y| < \delta$ but $|f(x) - f(y)| > 1$. The key is the dependence of $x$ and $y$ on $\delta$. To this end, let $\delta > 0$ be given, and choose $y = x + \frac{\delta}{2}$. Then $|x-y| = \frac{\delta}{2} < \delta$, but 
$$|f(x) - f(y)| = |x^2 - y^2| = \left|x^2 - \left(x^2 + x\delta + \frac{\delta^2}{4}\right)\right| = \left|x\delta + \frac{\delta^2}{4}\right|,$$
and for sufficiently large (or small) $x \in \mathbb{R}$, we can make the last quantity larger than 1. Hence we do not have uniform continuity on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: nice, you are smarter than Euler

Answer (score 4):

$x^2$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$ because continuous functions are always uniformly continuous on a compact set.

In your proof, you need $|x+x_0|<2$ to prove uniform continuity, which is true on $[0,1]$ but not on $\mathbb{R}$. So the proof cannot be extended to $\mathbb{R}$.